# how to flow inputs from workflow_run

Tags: github, github-actions

How can I get the inputs of a workflow which trigger a dependant workflow via `workflow_run`?
At the dependent workflow I like to get access to the inputs of the workflow triggered it.

```
name: depend

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["trigger"]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  test:
    name: test-on-dependent
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: context limit
        run: echo  ${{ inputs.limit }}
```

```
name: trigger

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      limit:
        type: number
        required: true

jobs:
  test:
    name: test-on trigger
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: limit
        run: echo  ${{ inputs.limit }}
```

Comment: I made a test [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/6049296136/job/16416310236) to check the `workflow_run` event payload and there is no input field so you can't get customizable input values from the previous workflow. In that case, the workaround could be to use a [workflow_dispatch event providing inputs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#providing-inputs) at the end of the first workflow, to trigger the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Using workflow events it appears to be not possible.

I added step to check if inputs are available in dependant step but they are not

```
      - name: Dump GitHub context
        env:
          GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJSON(github) }}
        run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
```

Your workaround could what GuiFalourd mentioned. At the end fo the workflow you could use Github Cli to trigger another workflow witch workflow_dispatch

```
jobs:
  comment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: |
            gh workflow run run-tests.yml -f logLevel=warning -f tags=false -f environment=staging
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FULL_PAT }}
```