How to use variable of workflow_dispatch pipeline into a workflow_run pipeline in GitHub Actions?
How can I use input variables mentioned in the workflow_dispatch pipeline in my workflow_run pipeline?
I can save input variables to environment variables if only they can be retrieved or I can even make the output variables but How to retrieve these variables in workflow_run is unknown to me can someone help me with this?
sample workflow_dispatch pipeline:
name: Deploy Manual Pipeline

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      env:
        description: 'The runtime environments of pipeline.'
        required: true
        default: 'Development'
        type: choice
        options:
          - Development
          - QA
          - Stage
          - Production

env:
  inputvariable: ${{ inputs.version }}


jobs:
  deploy-to-abc:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    outputs:
    my_output: ${{ inputs.version }}

    steps:
      - name: check variable
        run: echo the input is ${{ inputs.version }}

sample workflow_run pipeline:
name: Some checks Pipeline

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Deploy Manual Pipeline"]
    types: [completed]
    branches: [dev, qa]

jobs:
  deploy-to-xyz:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04 

    steps:
      - name: check variables
        run: |
          echo ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion }}
          echo ${{ github.event.workflow_run.head_branch }}
          echo ${{ github.inputs.version }} # how to get this?
      echo ${{ github.env.inputvariable }} # how to get this?
      ech0 ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion.outputs.my_output }}" # how to get this?


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77021205/how-to-flow-inputs-from-workflow-run
